# Como imprimir contenido de un webview en android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Muy buenas tardes, estoy tratando de imprimir el contenido de un webview en android en una impresora mini bluetoo pero no he podido hacerlo, esto es lo que tengo me carga la web pero necesito imprimir lo que carga.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    bar=(ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar2);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new myWebclient());
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());

    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    webView.loadUrl("http://www.miweb.com/index.html");

}

public class myWebclient extends WebViewClient{
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        bar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        bar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); //* muestra ProgressBar
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if((keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && webView.canGoBack()){
        webView.goBack();
        return true;
    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Lo que puedes hacer es imprimir una imagen primero con tu impresora bluetooth de ahi puedes sacar un screenshoot del webview e imprimir esa imagen.

Con este codigo podras crear un objeto File y generar un screenshoot del webview.

```
public File getBitmapFromwebchartView(WebView webView) {
        File file = null;
        if (webView != null) {
            webView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            Bitmap b = webView.getDrawingCache();
            if (b != null) {
                try {
                    file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                            System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");

                    // write the bytes in file
                    FileOutputStream fo;

                    fo = new FileOutputStream(file);

                    b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 60, fo);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        return file;
    }
```

Lo unico que faltaria seria que sepas como imprimir una imagen con tu impresora, ya que dependiendo de la impresora varia el codigo. Ejemplo puede que tu impresora sea marca Zebra, Bixolon, Mobiprint, StarIO, etc. Hay una infinidad de impresoras bluetooth y cada una tiene su forma de imprimir segun su libreria, si especificaras la marca seria mas facil, pero en contexto esa es la idea.